# Writing C++ without exceptions?

Tags: c++, exception

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26643898/200783) mentions two ways to handle a C++ library (such as Qt) which is not exception safe:

1. Isolate it in exception-safe wrappers
2. Give up exceptions and adapt to its style

The answer goes into detail about the first option, but what are the consequences of the second option: giving up exceptions?

When writing C++ without exceptions, how is the use of the language restricted? For example, are there parts of the standard library which are not safe to use?

(In particular, I assume that in the case of std::bad_alloc, I would have no choice but for my program to exit?)

Comment: `std::bad_alloc` can be circumvented by using the non-throwing version of `new`, e.g. `foo* f = new (std::nothrow) Foo;`

Comment: @user657267 - Can std::nothrow be made to work with the standard containers? I assume a custom allocator would be required - is it possible for it to report allocation failure without throwing?

Comment: What does Qt do when allocation fails?

Comment: @PaulBaker You would definitely have to write your own allocator as the default allocator calls the throwing version of `new` (which **must** throw on error, no exceptions (har har)). `new (std::nothrow)` returns a null pointer on failure.

Comment: @MattMcNabb - According to [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/exceptionsafety.html), it generally throws std::bad_alloc. The expectation seems to be that this should cause the application to exit.

Comment: qt seems to not know what it wants to do - it's not exception-safe and yet throws on a bad alloc?

Comment: Sounds good to me, just don't handle bad_alloc, or handle it at `main()` sort of level.

Comment: You don't have to give up exceptions *completely*... you just have to avoid throwing them from functions that might be called from Qt code, where you don't catch them before returning to Qt code.  You say *"The answer goes into detail about the first option"* but a lot of that detail is actually about the second option - worth your reading again....

Comment: @user657267: Actually, Qt throws on bad alloc sometimes, and other times returns an error code, and other times succeeds with a null object. I suspect this means that Qt is a large number of people over a large span of time and therefore maybe a bit schizophrenic. :)

Comment: More generally, Qt is mostly exception neutral, and sometimes offers relevantly stronger guarantees, but (a) you can't throw exceptions through slots, (b) it has various quirks that are there for legacy reasons, and (c) it has bugs and they essentially say they don't expect to ever fix them all. So, for simple programs, you can sometimes pretend it's exception safe and write workarounds when you find bugs, but for bigger programs, the OP is probably right to put more thought into it up-front.

Answer (score 2):

It's not hard. In fact I argue that the `Result<T>` style (also known as [`expected<T>` in Andrei's talk](https://youtu.be/kaI4R0Ng4E8), but I was inspired by [Rust's version](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html), particularly the [`try!` macro](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.try!.html), except that I don't template my `Err` variant (for functions that fail, all errors are the same)) is a lot *easier* than using exceptions.

The one thing you really have to give up is constructors that do something that can possibly fail. Instead, use the named constructor idiom and only use pretty-much-aggregate constructors after you've already done.

As far as `bad_alloc`, just let it kill the process by unwinding.

Comment: The nice thing about this is it's very easy to wrap up traditional C style error return, exception-throwing functions, and weird things like successfully returning an object that has to be checked for validity so they all act the same way.

Comment: The problem with it is that, as you say, you basically can't use constructors directly. Which means you're losing half the advantage of RAII. (And honestly, C++ without RAII is painful and almost pointless to me…) You can simulate this by, e.g., wrapping everything in `owned_pointer<>` (and with Qt's heavyweight objects, it's hard to imagine anyone worrying about the performance costs of that), but at that point… why aren't you just using a language with pure reference semantics in the first place?

Comment: @abarnert constructors are kind of pointless, destructors are all that really matters and you don't lose those.

Comment: If you can't construct anything on the stack, then you can't use destructors to clean up at the end of the stack frame. (Again, of course you can get around with `unique`/`owned`/`auto`/etc.`_ptr` values, but it's still less convenient, and slightly heavier-weight.)

Comment: @abarnert that is complete an utter BS. I have destructors on classes with no constructor **all the time**.

Comment: You're going to have named constructors on a wrapper type `T` that return a `T` (not a `T*` or similar), when that type's job is to wrap non-movable, expensive-or-non-copyable types like Qt collections and locks and GUI widgets?

Comment: @abarnert non-movable objects are strictly forbidden, and copy ctors are discouraged.

Comment: I don't understand what your response means. Maybe if you show the code for how you'd wrap a `QExpensiveObject` in a way that allows it to be used on the stack, without a constructor, without either you or the user of your wrapper using an explicit smart pointer?